# impala error: could not retrieve transaction read-only status from server. why?

Tags: cloudera-cdh

I used jdbc: hive2 to connect Impala, but the problem was that after flashing new metadata on a table, I encountered two errors when accessing the table after a period of time

1. Failed to load metadata for table
2. Could not retrieve transaction read-only status from server

This situation occurs randomly, which is why

My hiveServer2 is highly available. Impala version 3.2

How to solve the problem where the same version of hiveServer2 is not highly available in the testing environment

Comment: Invalid metadata was already used before the error occurred